# Have a header only project as a dependency with bjam

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

I have a bjam project which consists only of header files. I want to include these as a dependency in a separate Jamfile but unless I make the collection of headers into a library (by adding a single *.cpp) I don't see how I can do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to, unless you're doing something weird with the preprocessor and `#include`'s. Bjam knows how to scan source files for `#include`'s and automatically rebuilds them whenever the headers change. If that's not happening for you, you should ask about it on the [Boost.Build mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost-build).